# To search for string in a file and print the contents to file

Tags: powershell

I have a situation where I need to search for a particular string from the end of file occurring first from the end . On reaching upon the string I need to make another validation step to check for another string.
For example , I need to search for string "Hello" from the end of file. For the first time when I traverse "Hello" from the end, I need to continue to search for another string "Starting" which is exactly 5 lines above the "Hello" line.

I tried below code snippet which search for "Hello" string. How can I search for "Starting" string from "Hello"?

```
$Test   = "C:\Temp\Test.txt"
$looking = "Hello"
$Morelooking = "Starting"
$Info = Get-Content -Path $Test
if(Get-Content -Path $Test)
    {
        if (($Info -like $looking).Count -eq 0) 
        {
            Write-Output "Not found"
        }
        else
        {
            $Output = @()
                for($i = ($Info.Count -1); $i -ge 0; $i--) 
                {
                    $Output += $Info[$i]
                    if ($Info[$i] -like $looking) 
                    { 
                        break;
                    }
                }
            [array]::Reverse($Output)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file is looking something like this:

```
blah blah blah 
blah blah
Starting something
blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah 
blah 
Hello World
the end
```

you can loop through the lines of the file in reversed order

```
$Test        = "C:\Temp\Test.txt"
$looking     = "Hello"
$Morelooking = "Starting"
$Info        = Get-Content -Path $Test

# because we use the regex `-match` operator, escape the search terms
$looking     = [Regex]::Escape($looking)
$Morelooking = [Regex]::Escape($Morelooking)

# loop through the lines in reversed order
for ($i = $Info.Count -1; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
    if ($Info[$i] -match $looking) {
        Write-Host "'$looking' found in line $($i + 1)" -ForegroundColor Green  # humans count from line 1
        if ($i -gt 4 -and $Info[$i - 5] -match $Morelooking) {
            Write-Host "'$Morelooking' found in line $($i - 4)`r`n" -ForegroundColor Green
            # print the lines from the array where the matches are found
            ($i - 5)..($Info.Count -1) | ForEach-Object { $Info[$_] }
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "'$Morelooking' not found" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
        break
    }
}
```

Output:

```
'Hello' found in line 8
'Starting' found in line 3

Starting something
blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah 
blah 
Hello World
the end
```

Comment: I want the file to be read from end of the file., Not from begining. So the output be like Hello found at line 8

Comment: @MYstery .. That's why the loop goes in **reversed** order: `for ($i = $Info.Count -1; $i -ge 0; $i--) {` starting at the last line and working its way up, and yes.. the output correctly says `'Hello' found in line 8`

Comment: can we make the contents to print by using array variable till the search string is found from the end of file?

Comment: @MYstery I have edited the code to also print out the lines of the array from where the matches are found.

Answer (score 0):

To get the 5 lines above a certain match, you can use [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)'s `-Context` parameter:

```
# Let's start by escaping the search terms
$looking = [regex]::Escape($looking)
$Morelooknig = [regex]::Escape($Morelooking)

# Search for the "hello" string, ask for 5 lines of "pre-context"
enter code here
$matchesWithContext = Select-String -Path $Test -Pattern $looking -Context 5,0 -AllMatches

# Select that _last_ match:
$lastMatchWithContext = $matchesWithContext |Select -Last 1

# Test if the 5th line above (the first of our pre-context lines) contains "starting"
$lastMatchWithContext.Context.PreContext[0] -match $Morelooking
```